# Why is this PHP connection failing?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection

This connection seems to be failing. not sure why. Just trying to make this connection work so the rest of the project works.

```html
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "david_schema";

// Create connection
$connection = mysql_connect('$servername', '$username', '$password');

// Check connection
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
} 

$select_db = mysql_select_db('$dbname');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Comment: because, variables don't get parsed in single quotes.

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php

Comment: putting double quotes didn't change anything.

Comment: Have you tried manually connecting with these credentials at MYSQL console?

Comment: well then, my guess is that you can't use the mysql_ API anymore or that your connection failed outright.

Comment: Why would I not be able to use mysql_ API?

Comment: Beats me. I don't know which version of PHP you're using, or how you're accessing this. as localhost or file:/// ?

Comment: it's just a local MySql server and some php. should work. You sure you don't see any other problems?

Comment: mysql_* functions have been removed from 7.0, and deprecated in previous versions. You should switch to PDO or mysqli to prevent future headaches. Without the error message, it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: you need to remove all the single quotes around all the variables, including the one in this `$select_db = mysql_select_db('$dbname');` and pass the variable to it and see if that works `$select_db = mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);`

Comment: @daveywavey42 Ping me with the @ symbol and followed by my name or  anyone's name (no space between @ and the name) and that will send a messge to that person. So, ping me if you want to say if it worked or not.

Comment: You didn't put database for connection